# decrypt C# encrypted string in PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt a string in PHP.

I use this code for encrypting the string in C#:

```
    public string EncryptMessage(string text, string key)
    {
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.BlockSize = 256;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        aes.Key = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(key);
        aes.GenerateIV();

        string IV = ("specialstring" + Encoding.Default.GetString(aes.IV));

        ICryptoTransform AESEncrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        byte[] buffer = plainTextBytes;

        return
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Encoding.Default.GetString(AESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) + IV));

    }
```

I also use this code for decrypting the string in PHP:

```
function decrypt($text, $pkey)
{
    $key = $pkey;
    $text = base64_decode($text);
    $IV = substr($text, strrpos($text, "specialstring") );
    $text = str_replace("specialstring".$IV, "", $text);
    $res = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $IV), "\0");
    return $res;
}
```

The PHP code always return empty string. Whats wrong in my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: First problem: using `Encoding.Default` at all - and doing so to convert from binary to a string and then back again. The *only* effect that can have is to lose data. Just use `Convert.ToBase64String(AESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(...))`

Comment: I see you're using `Encoding.Default.GetString` to "encode" the IV as well. Again, that will potentially lose data - you should be using base64 for that. Basically, *any* time you're trying to encode arbitrary binary data as text, you should use base64 or hex.

Comment: OMG ! OPS, I used that in my program and user use from that right now, i don't have any chance now :( right ?

Comment: You mean you've stored the broken data, without ever verifying that you could decrypt it? Chances are pretty high that you've got problems, yes. It partly depends on what the default encoding is though. I would *start* by trying to decrypt the data in C#. If you can do that (by fluke) then you can potentially re-encrypt everything in a more sensible way, then work out the PHP side separately.

Comment: Oh, and I see you've got a *third* use of `Encoding.Default.GetBytes`, for the key. I missed that before. You should almost **never** use `Encoding.Default`.

Comment: I think that's correct method bcz i have one for other project and now after try to decrypte i see that is not correct :(

Comment: Consider using a 128-bit block size, then it is essentially AES and interoperability is improved. Using null padding is problematic in that is is not-standard, not supported widely and will not work with binary data,instead use PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding. The IV should be random bytes, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding bugs dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.